# Creating a Constraint as a Trigger in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

So I've seen plenty of trigger examples in phpMyAdmin, but the syntax isn't making sense to me... I'm way oversimplifying it.

I want to create a constraint on phpMyAdmin. I have two tables, one is Funds, and one is Fund_Shares_Purchased. In Funds, there is an attribute "total_available", which is the total number of shares that can be purchased. In Fund_Shares_Purchased, there is an attribute "quantity", which is how many shares somebody has bought. The two tables are related on the "Fund_Name" attribute.

I tried the following...

```
CREATE TRIGGER limitFundShares
BEFORE INSERT ON Fund_Shares_Purchased
BEGIN
    IF (Fund.total_shares < NEW.quantity)
    THEN
        RAISERROR("You can't buy that many shares of the fund!")
    END IF;
END;
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting from the use of `Fund.total_shares`?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a tested example using MySQL command line client:

```
create table Fund(total_shares int);
insert into Fund values(10);
create table Fund_Shares_Purchased(quantity int);

delimiter //
create trigger LimitFundShares
    before insert on Fund_Shares_Purchased
    for each row
    begin
      if ((select total_shares from Fund) < new.quantity)
      then
        signal sqlstate '45000' 
         set message_text = "You can't buy that many shares of the fund!";
       end if;
    end//

delimiter ;
insert into Fund_Shares_Purchased values (5);
insert into Fund_Shares_Purchased values (15);
insert into Fund_Shares_Purchased values (7);
select * from Fund_Shares_Purchased;
```

You should be able to paste the trigger creation statement into phpMyAdmin, although I have not tested that.

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to. Says the SQL syntax is wrong around the IF line